# Does ElasticSearch Keep Count The Number Of Times A Record Is Returned In A Given Period Of Time?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an ElasticSearch instance and it does one type of search - it takes a few parameters and returns the companies in its index that match the parameters given.

I'd like to be able to pull some stats that essentially says "This company has been returned from search queries X number of times in the past week".

Does ElasticSearch store metadata that will allow to pull this kind of info from it?  If this kind of data isn't stored in ES out of the box, is there a way to enable it?

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch (not ElasticSearch ;) ) does not do this natively, no. you can build something using the [slow log](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.3/index-modules-slowlog.html), where you set the timing to 0 to get it to log everything, but that then logs everything which may not be useful/too noisy

things like https://www.elastic.co/enterprise-search, built on top of Elasticsearch, do provide this sort of insight